# Pinyin font with larger diacritics

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts, font-design, font-forge

Where can I find a Pinyin don't with larger than normal diacritics? When positioned next to Chinese characters, e.g.. in a list, they would make the intonation of the characters more obvious.

(Many dictionaries, such as the Oxford Chinese dictionary, in my opinion, could do much better at imprinting a stamp of the characters' pronunciation in the mind, because if the diacritics is large, then the diacritic, which is the hardest part of the syllable to remember (for most learners), will be absorbed more easily).

Thanks..

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/75838/edit) and add an image example of the result you're looking for? Would be easier to help you out